# ASPNet Dropdown List from 0 to quantity available

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net

I'm creating a webform for a Class assignment that essentially allows you to select a quantity from 0 to the amount available for each product. We're using AdventureWorks 2014 as our datasource.

However it only displays the maximum quantity and not from 0 to the max quantity.

I'm just stuck on what to add so it can display 0 to max quantity. Thanks.

I don't have anything in regards to the code behind, it's just the basic:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void ddlQuantity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide code-behind and markup part of both dropdowns? I think your query returns a `SUM(Production.ProductInventory.Quantity)` as single number (1085) but not iterating it from 0 and assign those numbers from a list.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto is right. even that you grouping by Production.Product.Name but remember you also filter the group where (production.product.Name = @ProductName)  this cause the value will always return single value since it will only return the sum of the filtered product.name

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Updated the post with the code-behind(Which I haven't touched) and markup. We never learned much about the code-behind hence why it's still default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform binding by handling `SelectedIndexChanged` event from `ddlProductName` to fill `ddlQuantity` items:

**ASPX**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProductName" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="ddlProductNameitems" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name"
                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlProductName_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlQuantity" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" ...></asp:DropDownList>
```

Then use a `List` collection to store all numbers from 0 to maximum value set by SUM query then bind that `List` to `DropDownList` in `SelectedIndexChanged` event given above:

**ASPX.cs (code-behind)**

```cs
protected void ddlProductName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> quantities = new List<string>();
    int maxQuantity = 0;

    // retrieve SUM result from SqlDataSource
    // if 'DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty' doesn't work, try other 'DataSourceSelectArguments' options
    DataView view = QuantityChoices.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty) as DataView;

    // set maximum quantity from SUM query result
    if (view != null)
    {
        maxQuantity = int.Parse(view.Table.Rows[0]["TotalInventory"].ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        // assign maxQuantity from SqlConnection here
    }

    // add every quantity amount to the list...
    for (int i = 0; i <= maxQuantity; i++)
    {
        quantities.Add(i.ToString());
    }

    // ... then sort from least value...
    quantities.Sort();

    // ... and bind the list here!
    ddlQuantity.DataSource = quantities;
    ddlQuantity.DataBind();        
}
```

NB: `System.Data` namespace should be added to use `DataView` component. Note that it may necessary to remove `DataSourceID`, `DataTextField` & `DataValueField` from `ddlQuantity` to bind corresponding `DropDownList` with generated list of quantities.

Comment: Try removing `DataSourceID`, `DataTextField` & `DataValueField` attributes from `ddlQuantity` and see what happens next. Conflict may occur when `DataSource` assigned from code-behind but actually it retrieves data from `DataSourceID` attribute.